# Stanford Stanza -- Dependency Parsing Module -- Output for document with more than one sentence

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I have a query about formatting the **output** of the **dependency parsing module** when the document to be parsed contains more than one sentence.

One of the examples of using the dependency parsing module in the Stanza manual (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/depparse.html) is as follows:

```
import stanza
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='fr', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse')
doc = nlp('Nous avons atteint la fin du sentier.')
print(*[f'id: {word.id}\tword: {word.text}\thead id: {word.head}\thead: {sent.words[word.head-1].text if word.head > 0 else "root"}\tdeprel: {word.deprel}' for sent in doc.sentences for word in sent.words], sep='\n')
```

This example contains only one sentence. I would like to revise this code for a document that has more than one sentence. More specifically, I would like to revise the code so that all lines include a reference to the relevant sentence number.

The following is what I myself have come up with:

```
import stanza 
nlp = stanza.Pipeline(lang='en', processors='tokenize,mwt,pos,lemma,depparse ')
doc = nlp("Chris Manning teaches at Stanford University. He lives in the Bay Area.")
for i, sentence in enumerate(doc.sentences):
     print(*[f'sentence: {i+1}\tid: {word.id}\tword: {word.text}\thead id: {word.head}\thead: {sentence.words[word.head-1].text if word.head > 0 else "root"}\tdeprel: {word.deprel}' for word in sentence.words], sep='\n')
```

This seems to work properly. However, given that I have little experience with writing code, I would very much appreciate knowing if what I have come up with is okay or whether you would recommend doing something different.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.